# How can I get the return of a function called from a vector std::vector that contains std::function

Tags: c++, function, templates, struct, lambda

I have a structure that in its constructor receives an initialization list `std::initializer_list<P...>` of type parameter pack. That constructor is filled with lambda functions, and they are saved in a `std::vector<P...>`.

How can I get the return of those functions when traversing the vector calling each function?

Here is an example of the structure and what I want to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

struct my_type {
    my_type(){}
    my_type(string _value) : value(_value) {}
    string value = "test";
    string getValue(){return value;}
};


template<typename A, class...P>
struct struct_name {
  struct_name(std::initializer_list<P...> list)  : functions(list) {}
  std::vector<P...> functions;
  
  string value;
  my_type type;      

  string execute_functions(){
     for (size_t i = 0; i < functions.size(); i++)
    {
     value = functions[i](type);  // something like this, this does not work
    }
    return value;
    std::cout << value;
  }
};

typedef struct_name<std::function<void(my_type)>, std::function<void(my_type)>> _functions;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    _functions object = {
      [](my_type var)->string{
        return var.getValue();
      },
      [](my_type var)->string{
        return var.getValue();
      },
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works perfect except the way to obtain those values. I don't know how, and no matter how hard I look I can't find answers.

EDIT: I can't paste the complete code, because it depends on many other classes. I tried to recreate that section, the type is a parameter pack because it receives multiple types besides lambdas, but in the example I just put it that way.

Comment: it's unclear to me if you want to process a value between each function call (so they must accept and return the same type) or you want to have different functions and transform them to different value, because `std::vector<P...>` doesn't look something you'd want to do.

Comment: Please show a complete, but a [mre] that demonstrates your compilation error. There are a number of things about the shown code that simply doesn't make sense. It is very likely that `std::vector<P...>` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: A lambda that returns **void** (as per `->void`) and then has `return "something";` doesn't jibe.  Yet "works perfect".  Seems very odd.

Comment: a update the code, sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `std::tuple`, if you want to store arbitrary callable objects.

You can combine [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) with a fold expression for calling the functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using std::string;

struct my_type {
    my_type(){}
    my_type(string _value) : value(_value) {}
    string value = "test";
    string getValue(){return value;}
};

template<class...P>
struct struct_name {
    struct_name(P... args)
        : functions(args...)
    {}

    std::tuple<P...> functions;

    std::string value;
    my_type type;

    std::string execute_functions() {
        return execute_helper(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(P)>{});
    }
private:
    template<size_t ...Is>
    std::string execute_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        ((value += std::get<Is>(functions)(type)), ...);
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct_name foo(
        [](my_type var)->string {
            return var.getValue();
        },
        [](my_type var)->string {
            return var.getValue();
        });
    std::cout << foo.execute_functions() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to process a value through a series of function you can just use `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::function<float(float)>> functions = {
    [] (float f) { return f*f; },
    [] (float f) { return f + 2; }
  };
    
  float result = std::accumulate(functions.begin(), functions.end(), 1.5f, 
    [] (float v, const auto& lambda) {
      return lambda(v); 
    }
  );
    
  std::cout << 1.5f << " -> " << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But a vector can only contain one specified type, so what you are trying to do with you parameter pack `P...` doesn't make much sense, if you want to process multiple values through multiple functions with different signatures you'd better try with something like `std::tuple<std::function<T1(T2)>, std::function<T3(T4)>, ...>` and pass multiple values to it.

Comment: I already found the solution but I still wrote down this thank you very much